# Clicking checkbox works only for the first instance VBA Selenium (Element click intercepted)

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

For two hours, I am trying to fix a problem of checking checkboxes on webpage that is loaded by JavaScript.
Here's the html page for the desired page
https://pastebin.com/Q1q28dR8

Here's my code till now

```
Private driver As New Selenium.ChromeDriver
Const sURL As String = "https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/"

Sub Test()
        With driver
        .Start "Chrome", sURL
        .Get sURL
        '#https://eservices.moj.gov.kw/#
        '//*[@id="loginDiv"]/div/a[1]
        .Wait 2000
        ''.FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='loginDiv']/div/a[1]").Click
        .FindElementByClass("headerTabLeft").Click
        .Wait 3000
        .FindElementById("txtUserID").SendKeys "username"
        .FindElementById("txtPWD").SendKeys "password"
        .FindElementById("txtCaptcha").Click
        
        .Wait 5000
        .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id='frmLogin']/input[3]").Click
        .Get sURL & "lawyerViews/lawOrders/"
        .FindElementByLinkText("أوامر أداء جاهزة للدفع").Click
        Dim dRows As Object
        Set dRows = .FindElementsByCss("table.table-striped tbody tr")
        'Debug.Print dRows.Count
        .FindElementById("checkAll").Click
        .Wait 3000
        .FindElementById("checkAll").Click
        .Wait 3000
        Dim r As Long
        For r = 1 To dRows.Count
            Dim sRequestID As String
            sRequestID = dRows.Item(r).FindElementsByTag("td")(2).Text
            Dim x
            x = Application.Match(Val(sRequestID), ActiveSheet.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(x) Then
backP:
            .Wait 2000
                On Error Resume Next
                On Error GoTo backP
                .FindElementByXPath("//*[@id=""toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]""]").Click
                .Wait 2000
                '.FindElementByXPath("//input[@type='checkbox'][@value='200512308']").Click
                '.FindElementById("toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]").WaitSelection True, 20000
                '.Wait 2000
                '.FindElementByCss("[type=checkbox][value='" & sRequestID & "']").Click
                '.FindElementById("toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]").Click
                
                On Error GoTo 0
            
            Debug.Print sRequestID & " Checked"
            End If
        Next r
        Stop
    End With
End Sub
```

The first checkbox is only selected then I got an error message saying "Element click intercepted"
I tried using id, xpath, css and no way
Any ideas?

Comment: So, on which line please is this message occurring? And what is the value of the url being used at that point?

Comment: Thanks a lot my tutor. The tries is after the line `If Not IsError(x) Then`. I am trying to check the chekboxes after matching it from column A in activesheet. If number is found on sheet, then to check the checkbox related to that number. as an example `200512308` .. No specific url for each checkbox. I think this javascript.

Comment: This page `.FindElementByLinkText("أوامر أداء جاهزة للدفع").Click`. This is element inspection `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="dealSideLinkPage('/lawyerViews/lawOrders/readyToPay.jsp')">أوامر أداء جاهزة للدفع</a>`

Comment: The value returned is a table `Set dRows = .FindElementsByCss("table.table-striped tbody tr")` and in that table rows and each row has its own checkbox like that `<input type="checkbox" id="toBePaid[0]" name="toBePaid" value="200512308">`. 0 for the first row, 1 for the second row,2 for the third row and so on.

Comment: Can you match on the element without .click? Either with or without F8 wait?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225688/discussion-between-yasserkhalil-and-qharr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst not ideal for automation, it seems one workaround, from working through ths in chat, is to enact the click via javascript and ensure to use an attribute, rather than id, css selector

```
.ExecuteScript "document.querySelector(""[id='toBePaid[" & r - 1 & "]']"").click();"
```